# "Total score" based on multiple "above/below median values"

Tags: r

I am new to R and I have a problem that I simply cant find the solution to. I have tried reading through older posts etc. but I can't figure out how it could/should be done. I hope that some of you might be able to help.

Using the mtcars dataset as an example,

```
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

I wish to assign the cars a value (e.g. 1) if for instance the `hp` valvue is above the median and 0 if below. This could be called "hp_index".

I would do the same for lets say `cyl`, `disp` and `drat`, and then, I would like to assign the cars an "index_score" where a car for instance would be given the value 1 if a minimum of 3 out of the 4 `hp`, `cyl`, `disp` and `drat` is above median (that is, if 3 or 4 out of the 4 "hp_index", "cyl_index", "disp_index" and "drat_index" is 1).

Once again, I really hope that some of you might be able to help!

Thanks in advance, and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

In this case based on all the columns, otherwise specific columns can be selected

```
mtcars$index=rowSums(
  sapply(mtcars,function(x){
    ifelse(x>median(x),1,0)
  })
)

                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb index
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4     4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4     4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1     5
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1     4
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2     4
...
```

from here you can do another ifelse on the "index" column to decide whether it be 0 or 1.

To use different filters for columns, as you proposed

```
rowSums(
  cbind(
    sapply(mtcars[c("cyl", "disp", "drat")],function(x){ifelse(x>median(x),1,0)}),
    sapply(mtcars["hp"],function(x){ifelse(x<median(x),1,0)})
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems like a nice way to solve it.

I  wondered if you show me how the code would look when specific columns are selected? I tried to write ```mtcars[,4:6]```

Comment: @stqck8921 That's it, in the sapply call just `sapply(mtcars[,4:6], ...`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems like a nice way to solve it. 

I  wondered if you could show me how the code would look when specific columns are selected? I tried to write ```mtcars[,4:6]``` which works, but would it be possible to specify them by name, for instance ```mtcars["hp", "drat", "cyl"]```?

Comment: @stqck8921 Same deal, you forgot to use a vector for the column names `sapply(mtcars[c("hp", "drat", "cyl")], ...`.

Comment: It worked, thanks! So, for the last ifelse, to place the cars with a high total index score in a "high_score" group (that is, if they have 3 or more index scores = 1), I could write: ```mtcars$high_score <- ifelse(mtcars$index >= 3, 1, 0)```?

Comment: @stqck8921 Precisely. You could even nest it inside the current code, so that you have only 1 command. `mtcars$high_score <- ifelse(rowSums(...)>= 3, 1, 0)` .

Comment: Nice! And the last question: Would it be possible to adjust the code so that one of the values, for instance ```hp```, would get the ```hp_index``` = 1 for a value below the median, while the others (```cyl``` etc.) would get = 1 for values above the median? If that makes sense?

Comment: I tried this: ```mtcars$index=rowSums(
  sapply(mtcars[c("cyl", "disp", "drat")],function(x){
    ifelse(x>median(x),1,0)
  }),
  sapply(mtcars["hp"],function(x){
    ifelse(x<median(x),1,0)
  })
)``` Would that be correct?

Comment: @stqck8921 Close, you need to `cbind` the results from each sapply first. I pasted it into my answer, for better visibility.

Comment: Great! Thanks - really appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0):

here's a tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
  mutate(across(c(hp, cyl, disp, drat), .fns = ~if_else(.x >= median(.x), 1, 0), .names = "{.col}_index"),
         index_score = apply(across(c(hp_index, cyl_index, disp_index, drat_index)), 1, sum),
         index_score = if_else(index_score >= 3, 1, 0))
```

Note: I created the conditions in a way that I split with >= median and < median. If you only use > and < there could be edge cases with missings if the row has exactly the median.

First six cases:

```
   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb hp_index cyl_index disp_index drat_index index_score
1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4        0         1          0          1           0
2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4        0         1          0          1           0
3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1        0         0          0          1           0
4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1        0         1          1          0           0
5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2        1         1          1          0           1
6 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1        0         1          1          0           0
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I tried to write the code in R, but it couldn't find the across function. Do you have any idea why that might be, or is it just R?

Comment: It's in the tidyverse package.

Comment: I did install the package but it still couldn't find the function. I'll try to restart R and see if it works then :-)

Comment: And thanks for the clarification about splitting the median.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
cols <- c('cyl', 'disp', 'drat', 'hp')

mtcars %>%
  mutate(across(cols, list(index = ~+(.x > median(.x))))) %>%
  mutate(index_score = +(rowSums(select(., ends_with('index'))) >= 3)) -> result

result
```

Used `select(., ends_with('index'))` in `rowSums` assuming there are no other columns that end with `index` in your actual dataset apart from the newly created ones with `across`.

Comment: Curious, what does the `+` thing do in your code?

Comment: `+` at the front changes logical values to integer values. Try `+c(TRUE, FALSE)`

Comment: Ah I see. So it's basically a shortcut for ifelse (..., 1, 0)? Smart.

Comment: Thank you! That seems like a nice way to solve it as well! I wondered if, instead of using the median, would it be possible to use for instance the third qurtile or the top 33 % for the values? Would there be any commands for that?

Comment: You replace `+(.x > median(.x))` with `~+(.x > quantile(.x, .75))` to check for values greater than 3rd quartile.